# Read email credentials stored as GH secret

Tags: python, github, github-actions

I have a scraper in python that runs daily to collect numbers of new covid cases, but the problem is that the source website sometimes shows the numbers of the previous day. Whenever this happens, I want the python script to send me an email. The email has to be sent from python because there I evaluate if the collected values are the same as the previous day.

The scraper runs daily on GitHub Actions and I need to pass the sender email credentials to the python script, for which I plan to use `GitHub secrets`. Sender email account is @gmail.com

I have successfully ran the script locally, storing email credentials as environment variables.

---

What I've tried so far: I'm trying to mimic the approach explained by user Simran-B [here](https://github.community/t/using-secrets-for-code-and-database-credentials/135875/8?u=canovasjm). I created two secrets in the repo: `EMAIL_ADDRESS` and `EMAIL_PASSWORD`. I need to use these secrets *inside* the python script and this is the part I'm missing.

The `.yml` file in folder `.github/workflows` has these lines:

```yaml
- name: execute py script # run sj-gobierno.py to get the latest data
  env: | 
    EMAIL_ADDRESS: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_ADDRESS }}
    EMAIL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    python sj-gobierno.py
```

The `.py` script is called `sj-gobierno.py` and has the following lines:

```
# required libraries
import os
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

# check if the source dashboard has been updated. If not, send me an email
if (today_numbers == yesterday_numbers) == True:
    
    # get email and password from environment variables
    EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ.get('EMAIL_ADDRESS')
    EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
    
    # set up email content
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = 'GitHub Actions: covid-19-san-juan'
    msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
    msg['To'] = 'recipient@gmail.com'
    msg.set_content('Source webpage has not been updated.')
    
    # send email
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        smtp.send_message(msg)
```

In both chunks above I'm skipping other lines in the sake of brevity. I guess the problem is in the chunks above: the workflow was running successfully on GH Actions before I added the *send-email* feature. The current status of the workflow is 'failing'. [Here](https://github.com/canovasjm/covid-19-san-juan) is the link to the repo.

Question: How to read the email credentials, which are stored as GH secrets, in the python script?

EDIT: I added a `|` after `env:` to create a multi-line collection as shown [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1214409/Learn-YAML-in-five-minutes). Now I have `env: |`, but the problem persists.

Comment: I don't know if your actual file has that indentation, but if so, that may be part of your problem.  YAML is indentation sensitive.

Comment: Thanks! I checked indentation in my code and it seems correct. Reading about `.yml` indentation, I realized I was missing a `|` after `env: `, to create a multi-line collection as shown [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1214409/Learn-YAML-in-five-minutes). Now I have `env: |`, however, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per docs you won't need the `|` 
source in docs: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env

So try:

```yaml
env:
  EMAIL_ADDRESS: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_ADDRESS }}
  EMAIL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
```

Similar to your example above can be found in the docs here - https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow

Comment: Thanks. I read the documentation but the example shown there is only for one secret. I didn't know how to deal with 2 or more secrets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send emails from python, there are two things to take into account: 1) the `.yml` file to set the GH action and 2) the gmail account configuration.

---

1. As users [airtower-luna](https://github.community/t/using-secrets-for-code-and-database-credentials/135875/12?u=canovasjm) and [slajma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65355657/10152848) pointed out, there is no need for the `|` after `env:` 
   Also, user airtower-luna recommended to move the `pip install` to a separate, previous step so it doesn’t have access to the secrets.
2. There are 2 possible set up in gmail.

- **Didn't work:** Going to https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps and allowing less secure apps is not enough. Gmail blocked login attempts from python.
- **Worked:** Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security and enable two step verification.

[image]

Next, go to https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords and let Google generate a password for "Mail".

[image]

Copy the code and set as a secret in GitHub. In my case, I called this secret `EMAIL_PASSWORD`. Finally, inside your python script, you can access the secrets with `os.environ.get()`.

Fixed code in the [repo](https://github.com/canovasjm/covid-19-san-juan)